# How to speed up the sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, query-optimization

I have an SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT p.Id1,p.Id2,p.Id3 
FROM dataset1 p
WHERE p.Id2 IN (
    SELECT r.Id4 
    FROM dataset1 r 
    WHERE r.Id5=125 AND r.Id6>=100000000000000 AND r.Id6<1000000000000000
) 
ORDER BY p.Id1 DESC, p.Id2 DESC
```

However there appears to be huge amounts of data with Id6 in this range and thus, it takes a quite long time to compute. But I only have one hour to compute the query. I thus, am wondering if someone could help me to improve the performance of this query.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the execution plan (`EXPLAIN`) for your query, as well as information about the table schemas and indexes. It's difficult to help you optimize the query when we have no details available.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If a `TEXT` column is involved, some of the suggested indexes are invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Since the filtering seems to be done on `r`, arrange for it to be looked at first:

```
SELECT  p.Id1, p.Id2, p.Id3
    FROM  ( SELECT id4
       FROM dataset1 AS r
       WHERE  r.id5 = 125
         AND  r.Id6 >= 100000000000000
         AND  r.Id6 <  100000000000000 ) AS x
    JOIN dataset1 AS p  ON p.id2 = x.id4
    ORDER BY  p.Id1 DESC, p.Id2 DESC;
```

For that, these indexes should be beneficial:

```
INDEX(id5, id6, id4)   -- covering
INDEX(id2, id1, id3)   -- covering
```

You have a "range" test on `id6`, yet the range is empty.  I assume that was a mistake.  Please don't simplify a query too much; we might give you advice that does not apply.  I am assuming that the range is really a range.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` tend to optimize poorly when the subquery returns a lot of data. You can try using `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT p.Id1, p.Id2, p.Id3 
FROM dataset1 p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dataset1 r 
    WHERE 
        r.Id4 = p.Id2
        AND r.Id5 = 125 
        AND r.Id6 >= 100000000000000 
        AND r.Id6 <  100000000000000
) 
ORDER BY p.Id1 DESC, p.Id2 DESC
```

Then, consider a multi-column index on `(Id4, Id5, Id6)` to speed up the subquery. The idea is to put the more restrictive criteria first - so obviously you want `Id6` last, but you might want to try inverting the first two columns to see if any combination performs better than the other.

Side note: both the lower and upper bound for `Id6` have the same value in your query. I take this as a typo (otherwise your query would always return no row).

Comment: what does 'select 1' in line4 mean?

Comment: @FrankQ - The pattern is `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )`.  the `1` is not very critical, since the meaning is "does _any_ row exist".  And it is smart enough to stop without looking for _all_ rows, as would happen in a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance don't use an inner query. You can get you desired result by using an inner join too:

```
SELECT 
    p.Id1, p.Id2, p.Id3 
FROM 
    dataset1 p 
INNER JOIN 
    dataset1 r ON p.Id2 = r.Id4 
               AND r.Id5 = 125 
               AND r.Id6 >= 100000000000000 
               AND r.Id6 < 100000000000000
ORDER BY 
    p.Id1 DESC, p.Id2 DESC
```

Comment: The optimal indexes for this formulation are provided in my Answer.